# Listening on a port with UDP without spawning another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

Ever since I've learned multithreading concepts, I feel like I've been a little bit 'trigger happy', adding threads whenever I need to get a new task done, and I'm worried that I'm going a little overboard.

Is there any way to listen on a `DatagramSocket` (in java as an example) without creating a thread and having it block? Is that the generally accepted way of doing it, or is there a better/more standard way?

Comment: what's the problem with threads? : ) they are the thing to use for tasks like that

Comment: I'm not really a java guy, but I'm sure there is a way to make use of the `select` or `poll` system calls. From a brief web search, it appears that `java.nio.channels` is the way to go. Look for `DatagramChannel`, which can be registered with a `Selector` allowing you to wait for multiple channels at once, with the ability to implement timeouts as well.

Comment: @GilHamilton that's cool! I think I'll just go with the threaded approach. I was just worried that I was making too many java threads but I guess that's kinda the point of multithreading. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

@Brydon Gibson : If you don't want to create a thread, you can use the main or current Thread.

But you have to know that this thread will be blocked when listening with socket.receive() method. I don't know if that's what you want to do.

BTW, You only need one thread to listen to your socket.

[UDP Client/Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42450123/2619908)